# sstableloader to update existing columns

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Hi I am new to cassandra and was checking on sstableloader.

By the function of cassandra if any insert happens on the key which is already in Cassandra table the values will be updated. I tried using the same concept using sstableloader using MAP.

But instead of updating only the columns required it is updating the entire row. Is there any way we can insert only the columns required and leave the rest as was earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@root545, thank you for your interest.

So basically I was doing things wrong. Cassandra always inserts based on the key, if the y is already present then it will override the values for that key.

When you want to override any value for an existing key, Just provide the insert statement as insert into table(keys present in table, the values you want to override).

for example if we have a table like below.

create table example (
key1 text,
key2 text,
value1 text,
value2 text,
value3 text)
primary key(key1,key2)

then in order to update the value3 alone we need to provide the insert statement as

insert into example(key1,key2,value3) values (?,?,?)

and create the sstablewriter as

CQLSSTableWriter cqlssTableWriter = CQLSSTableWriter.builder().inDirectory().forTable().using().withPartitioner(new Murmur3Partitioner()).build();

This should do

Answer (score 0):

sstableLoader uses update for all inserts. What do you mean when you say it updates the entire row ? are you creating sstable manually and pushing them to cassandra ?